# Do damaging spells affect Hidden Tesla towers while the towers are still hidden?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Pretty much what's on the tin. Do Lightning and Earthquake spells damage Hidden Tesla towers while they are still hidden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no. If they are hidden and you have used your spell then it won't do any damage to them.

You can read [Here](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Hidden_Tesla)...(under the Trivia section)

Comment: Agreed and can tell as well from experience.