# Do spells hit Hidden Tesla when they are underground?

Tags: clash-royale

In Clash of Clans, spells [don't effect Hidden Tesla while are hidden](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/240409/120054). However, in Clash Royale you can see Tesla from the time they are placed. Do spells, such as poison and lightning, deal damage to them while they are underground?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I read this question the other day and noticed this tip while playing Clash Royal so I took a screenshot.

As long as the tesla is hidden underground it will not take damage.

[image: ![tesla tip on loading screen]

Answer (score 8):

No, hidden teslas will not be damaged while hidden. 
From the clash-royale [wiki](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Tesla) -
"When it retreats underground when not attacking, the Tesla is unaffected by Spells, such as the Rocket and Lightning.
It also cannot be targeted by cards that have a longer range than the Tesla, such as the X-Bow or the Princess, while hiding."

Answer (score 2):

It should be amended that as of the March 3rd 2020 [balance changes](https://clashroyale.com/blog/release-notes/season-9-balance-changes.html), the earthquake spell can do damage to the Tesla tower.